# VLC segmentation fault - XBMC core dumped

Tags: gnome, vlc, crash, xbmc, segmentation-fault

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 and VLC media player 3.0.0-git Vetinari (`revision 3.0.0~~git20141205+r58841+31~ubuntu14.10.1`)
 Since yesterday when I try to watch videos VLC crashes and I get:

```
(vlc:9850): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for ColoredPlastic has no name

Segmentation fault
```

I also tried downgrading from ppa to the ubuntu repository to vlc 2.2 and the crash persists. I have tried to purge vlc and re-install and also reset settings a few times; I hasn't changed anything.

Also I tried to use XBMC (ubuntu and ppa stable) and it does not start I get:

```
Error in `/usr/lib/xbmc/xbmc.bin': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007f75342e97b8
Aborted (core dumped)
/usr/bin/xbmc: 82: /usr/bin/xbmc: systemd-coredumpctl: not found
```

Update: I also tried with totem after update gstreamer and I get the following:

> (totem:3198): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme file for ColoredPlastic has no
>   name
>
> libva info: VA-API version 0.35.1 libva info: va_getDriverName()
>   returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva
>   error,driver_name=(null) libva info: VA-API version 0.35.1 libva info:
>   va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed
>   with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null) Segmentation fault

I am guessing it might be related to video drivers, I am running on an Intel i7-3517U.

thanks!

Comment: I am guessing it's related to the "ColoredPlastic" theme.

Comment: Thanks, tried changing back to default icon theme and VLC/Totem/XBMC still crash... I had installed the intel drivers when I was on ubuntu 14.04, then I upgraded to 14.10 so I am thinking that's what's causing the trouble; I guess I will have to re-install ubuntu to repair that.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The icon theme I was using was causing vlc to crash with a segmentation fault. Took forever to figure out.